# SQL: Error while calculating two subselect columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I know this is going to be another easy question for the SQL gurus since I'm sure I'm doing something wrong that is obvious. **This is all for SQL Server 2000** (inherited projects!)

I have a query like

```
   SELECT (SELECT Price1 from Table1) AS 'PriceOne', 
(SELECT Price2 From Table2) AS 'PriceTwo', 
PriceTwo * PriceOne AS 'Total'
```

But this generates an error of an unrecognized column for PriceOne and PriceTwo. I'm assuming its possible to multiply columns in this way, right?

Comment: Mostly a syntax issue, but also, what relationship exists to match prices from table1 to prices in table2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to be sure that those sub-querys are always going to return just one row. Now, for your specific issue about the column names, you need to wrapped them on another `SELECT` to use them like that:

```
SELECT PriceOne, ProceTwo, PriceTwo * PriceOne AS 'Total'
FROM (  SELECT  (SELECT Price1 from Table1) AS 'PriceOne', 
                (SELECT Price2 From Table2) AS 'PriceTwo') AS A
```

Comment: This is perfect and it worked. I knew it was something simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the column alias in the same SELECT context. Try:

```
SELECT (SELECT Price1 from Table1) AS 'PriceOne', 
(SELECT Price2 From Table2) AS 'PriceTwo', 
(SELECT Price1 from Table1) * (SELECT Price2 From Table2) AS 'Total'
```

Or specify your query as a subquery and select from it in an outer context:

```
SELECT PriceOne, PriceTwo, PriceTwo * PriceOne AS Total
FROM (SELECT (SELECT Price1 from Table1) AS 'PriceOne', 
         (SELECT Price2 From Table2) AS 'PriceTwo') x
```

---

Although, I wonder if `Table1` and `Table2` really have only one row in each, or if you're truly intending to do something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clarify the question.  Do Table1 and Table2 have more than one row in them?  If so, you need to specify some sort of join criteria, I'm assuming that you don't want a cartesian join.

Just curious, why would you multiply prices?  That doesn't make sense.  And then call the result 'Total' -- total usually means adding not multiplying.

Comment: I'm security paranoid, so I always "obfuscate" my questions with other table names & columns that have NOTHING to do with what I'm actually working on. So, I may be talking about "prices" in this post but I'm actually working on something else. The core of the solution will still work :-)